Convergence of a double integral with a parameter
Given the following double integral:
$$
\int_\alpha^\infty dx  \int_\alpha^\infty dy \frac{xy}{(x+y)^{\frac{\beta}{2}+1}}e^{-x-y}
$$
where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha\ge0$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{N}$, $\beta>1$. I want to find the values of the parameter $\beta$ such that the double integral converges in the limit $\alpha\to0$.
What I understand is that there is no divergence at $\infty$ since the exponential factor suppresses it, but it can be a divergence in $0$ (as $\alpha\to0$). Do you have any suggestion?

Let $1+\beta/2=\lambda$ and consider the integral
$$J:=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{xy}{(x+y)^{\lambda}}e^{-x-y} dx dy.$$
Change variables $x=s^2$ and $y=t^2$ to write
$$J=4\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{s^3 t^3}{(s^2+t^2)^{\lambda}}e^{-(s^2+t^2)} dsdt.$$
Now use spherical coordinates (change variables $s=r \cos{\theta}$, $t=r \sin{\theta}$) to get
$$J=C
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{r^6}{r^{2\lambda}}e^{-r^2} r dr=C
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{1}{r^{2\lambda-7}}e^{-r^2} dr,$$
where
$C=4\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\cos^{3}{\theta}\sin^{3}{\theta} d\theta$. Notice that $C$ is just a real number.
The last integral converges if and only if $2\lambda-7<1$, i.e, when
$\beta<6$.
Another solution
Consider the portion
$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
\frac{xy}{(x+y)^{\lambda}}dxdy$
Use the fact that $2xy\leq (x+y)^{2}$ to estimate
$$\frac{xy}{(x+y)^{\lambda}}\leq \frac{1}{2}
(x+y)^{2-\lambda}.$$
Now, do the $x$-integration first to get
$$|I|\leq c\int_{0}^{1}((1+y)^{3-\lambda}+y^{3-\lambda})dy,$$
for some constant $c$.
The first integral converges for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$
because the integrand is continuous on $[0,1]$, the second integral however converges only if $\lambda<4$ ($\beta<6$) . There is a caveat that if $\lambda-2=1$ the   $x$- integration gives $$\int_{0}^{1}(\log{(1+y)}-\log{y})dy.$$ But this last integral converges.

Cristal clear! Thanks!

You are welcome :)

Using, as @Medo, $\alpha=0$ and $k=1+\frac \beta 2$,
$$I=\int \frac{x\,y}{(x+y)^{k}}\,e^{-(x+y)}\,dy$$ $$I=x (x \,\Gamma (1-k,x+y)-\Gamma (2-k,x+y))$$
The definite inner integral is
$$-\frac{e^{-x}\, x^{3-k}}{k-1}+\frac{x (x+k-1) }{k-1}\,\Gamma (2-k,x)$$
For the first term
$$\int e^{-x}\, x^{3-k}\,dx=-\Gamma (4-k,x)$$ and the definite integral converges if $k<4$
(that is to say $\beta < 6$)
As a total
$$-\frac{\Gamma (4-k)}{k-1}+\frac{(k+5)\, \Gamma (4-k)}{6 (k-1)}=\frac 16\Gamma (4-k)=\frac 16\Gamma \left(3-\frac{\beta }{2}\right)$$
